# How to select checked checkbox dynamically from a component with a call of the function?

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, binding, angular7

I have a function inside the angular7 components. I want to call this function and get selected checkbox with id, class  whatever the possible solution.

```
get_selected_users(){
     checked_users = [01,333,43,54,656,234,234,324];
     checked_users.forEach(function(element) {
           console.log("element --->",element);
     });
```

Html code

```
<input type="checkbox" value="333" />
<input type="checkbox" value="54" />
<input type="checkbox" value="100" />
<input type="checkbox" value="999" />
```

Comment: Please provide a Stackblitz link with a reproducible example.

Comment: closing } is missing in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use below by including jquery:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

$.each(checked_users, function(i, val){

if($("input[value='" + val + "']"))
   $("input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Jquery is not the solution. I want to do it with angular 7.